# Hibernate @ManyToMany save

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

I have a @ManyToMany relation between tow tables (User and Work) in my Code as follow:

```
...
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_WORK", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "WORK_ID") 
})  
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Work> works;
...
```

And When i want to affect a new work to a user a execute the following code:

```
    ...
addWorkToUser(Work work,Integer idUser){ 
    User user = new User();
   user.setId(idUser);
   Set<Work> worksList = new HashSet<Work>();
   worksList.add(work);
   user.setWorks(worksList);
       getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(User)
}
    ...
```

The problem is when i affect a new work for the first time all goes well. But when i affect a new woks to the same user i see only the last work !!!
When i debug the code i found a delete Query.
How can i skip this delete query ?

```
Hibernate: update User set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from USER_WORK where USER_ID=?
Hibernate: insert into USER_WORK (USER_ID, WORK_ID) values (?, ?)
```

**EDIT**:

I get around the problem by executing that manually, 
But i'm still looking for the best solution 
:(

```
    User User = (User) DataAccessUtils
            .singleResult((getHibernateTemplate().find(
                    "From User WHERE id = ?", idUser)));
    User.getWorks().add(work);
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(User);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you add a work to a user, which already exists in the database, you create a new User (although it already exists), assign it a set of work containing a single element, and then update the existing user with the new one. Of course, the result is that the existing set of works is replaced by the new one, which contains a single element.

You shouldn't create a new user, since it already exists in the database. Instead, get the existing user from the database, and add the new work to his set of works:

```
// if the work isn't persistent yet:
session.persist(work);

User user = (User) session.get(User.class, idUser);
user.addWork(work);
// nothing else needed
```

Comment: I change my code to this :

Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
User User = (User) session.get(User.class, idUser);
Set<Work> groupsList = new HashSet<Work>();
groupsList.add(group);
User.setGroups(groupsList);
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(User);
session.close();

But i still have the same problem

Comment: Because you still replace the set by a new one containing a single work. You must add the work to the set of works the user has. Not replace the set by a new one. `user.getGroups().add(work);`. When you add a coin to your wallet, you don't construct a new wallet, put the coin in the new wallet, and replace the wallet in your pocket by the new one. You take your existing wallet in your pocket, already containing coins, and add the new coin inside. Same here.

Comment: i try that but it it didn't work for me.
I try with the flowing function : 

public void addWorkToUser(Work work,Integer idUser) {
  Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  User User = (User) session.get(User.class, idUser);
  session.saveOrUpdate(work);
  User.getGroups().add(work);
  session.saveOrUpdate(User);
  session.flush();
  session.close();
}

Comment: What didn't work? Why are you calling saveOrUpdate() on an attached user? Did I call it in my answer? No, I explicitely added: "nothing else needed".